# When typing rails s or rails g, rails scripts are not run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

First thing is I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

When I type rails s or rails g, a new rails app is created in folder /s and /g instead of the respective script being run.

When I type rails new, a new rails app with folder /new is created.

I'm not sure why this is happening. It only worked once when I first installed rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using Rails 2.x. Check your rails version,

```
 rails --version
```

to see your rails version.

`new` keyword is used in Rails 3.x. In Rails 2.x when you run command `rails project` it will create a project for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the local version of Rails via `./script/rails`, instead of whichever version of Rails (obviously version 2.x) is installed system-wide.